# Need csv file upload to fetch all rows but currently fetching the first row

Tags: php, laravel, csv, file-upload

This is the code to the upload function in my controller.The problem at hand is that when i upload the csv file to my database I only get(fetch) the first row of the file and the rest of the rows are omitted.I need to be able to get all the rows from the file.Please assist in anyway you can...Thanks in advance

```
public function upload(Request $request)
{   
    //get file
    //$allowed =  array('csv');
    $upload=$request->file('upload');
    //$extension = File::extension($upload);
    $filePath=$upload->getRealPath();


    //open and read
    $file=fopen($filePath,'r');
    $header= fgetcsv($file);
    $escapedHeader=[];

    //validate
    foreach ($header as $key => $value) {

        $lheader= strtolower($value);
        $escapedItem=preg_replace('/[^a-z]/', '', $lheader);

        array_push($escapedHeader, $escapedItem);

    }
    //looping throught other columns

    while ($columns=fgetcsv($file)) {

        if ($columns[0]=="") 
        {
            continue;
        }

        $data= array_combine($escapedHeader, $columns);
        dd($data);
        //setting type

        foreach ($data as $key => $value) {
            $value=($key=="phone" || $key=="nationalid" || $key=="staffsalary")?(integer)$value:(string)$value;
        }

        //table update
        $firstname=$data['firstname'];
        $lastname=$data['lastname'];
        $email=$data['email'];
        $phone=$data['phone'];
        $nationalid=$data['nationalid'];
        $staffid=$data['staffid'];
        $stafftitle=$data['stafftitle'];
        $staffsalary=$data['staffsalary'];


        $employees= Employees::firstOrNew(['phone'=>$phone,'nationalid'=>$nationalid]);
        $employees->firstname=$firstname;
        $employees->lastname=$lastname;
        $employees->email=$email;
        $employees->staff_id=$staffid;
        $employees->staff_title=$stafftitle;
        $employees->staff_salary=$staffsalary;
        $employees->employer_phone = Auth::user()->phone;
        $employees->save();

        return redirect()->route('home');

}
}
```

Comment: is your `$columns[0]` after row one empty by chance? Also, show us the CSV maybe please?

Comment: You can use this dependency, easy and simple. http://www.maatwebsite.nl/laravel-excel/docs

Comment: If one of the below posts has answered your question **please may you mark it as accepted** :) Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The main reason you're having this issue is because your `return redirect()->route('home');` is inside your `while` loop. Just move it so it's on the outside and it should work fine.

---

Also, this is just an FYI but you could use [Collections](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/collections) to clean your controller up a little but:

```
public function upload(Request $request)
{
    $upload = $request->file('upload');

    $csv = collect(array_map('str_getcsv', file($upload->getRealPath())));

    $keys = array_map(function ($item) {
        return preg_replace('/[^a-z]/', '', strtolower($item));
    }, $csv->shift());

    $csv
        ->map(function ($row) use ($keys) {
            return array_combine($keys, $row);
        })
        ->reject(function ($row) {
            return empty(array_first($row));
        })
        ->each(function ($row) {

            $row = array_map(function ($value, $key) {
                return in_array($key, ['phone', 'nationalid', 'staffsalary']) ? (integer)$value : (string)$value;
            }, $row);

            $employees = Employees::firstOrNew(['phone' => $row['phone'], 'nationalid' => $row['nationalid']]);
            $employees->firstname = $row['firstname'];
            $employees->lastname = $row['lastname'];
            $employees->email = $row['email'];
            $employees->staff_id = $row['staffid'];
            $employees->staff_title = $row['stafftitle'];
            $employees->staff_salary = $row['staffsalary'];
            $employees->employer_phone = Auth::user()->phone;
            $employees->save();
        });

    return redirect()->route('home');
}
```

Obviously, you don't have to use the code above, I just thought I'd show you an alternative way to write it.

I wasn't sure what `if ($columns[0]=="")` was there for but I've added that in with the `reject()` method.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is a different breakline for different OS. Use this construction for better:

```
    // take care of all possible newline-encodings in input file
    $NEWLINE_RE = '/(\r\n)|\r|\n/'; 

    $csv = preg_replace($NEWLINE_RE,'===BREAK===', $old_csv);
    foreach (explode('===BREAK===', $csv) as $k => $line){
       if(strlen($line) > 0) $lines[] = stripcslashes(trim($line));
    }
```